# Converting cartesian to polar form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

Given $$y^2 = x^2 - x^4,$$

how do you represent this in polar form?

I tried substituting $$x=r\cos \theta$$ and $$ y= r\cos \theta$$ which gave me $$r = \sqrt{\frac {\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta} {\cos^4 \theta}}
$$

However, the square root does not give a real number e.g. when $$\theta=1$$ $r$ is undefined.

What would be the correct equation then?

Comment: $\theta=1$ is not covered by this. Only points with $\sin^{2}(\theta) \leq \cos^{2}(\theta)$ are on this curve.

Comment: Formatting hint: When typing sine and cosine in math use `\sin` and `\cos` which improves readability. [edit] your question to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a plot makes clear: Your equation defines a closed curve for $x\in(-1,1)$

```
   Plot[ {1, -1}*x Sqrt[(1 - x^2)], { x, -1, 1 }]
```

[image: Lemniskate]

Since |x| is bounded by 1, the  replacement in polar coordinates yields

$$  \text{ParametricPlot[} \{\sin[ \phi], \cos[\phi] \sin[\phi\}, \{ \phi, -\pi, \pi \}]$$

same picture. The height of $1/2$  and the double loop is due to

$$\cos \phi\  \sin \phi  = \frac{1}{2}\  \sin (2\phi)$$